# Hosting Win32, WinForms or WPF Window by handle?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm investigating if it's possible to host any type of window in WPF by handle. I've been exploring the HwndHost class, although all the examples I've come across is using a Win32 handle. Is it possible to host any window type by handle?

Comment: **any** is a very strong word. For _any_ you should get only _probably_ (unless you're ready for long debugging sessions  and dirty tricks, you can't know what another app will do with his parent window...) That said there are good chances you can host any window in your WPF control, regardless technology used to build it. For the definitive answer you need to try

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Here is a quick link from MSFT on hosting Win32 controls:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970061.aspx

I've actually worked on a project where we hosted a Java client application (don't ask why) inside a WPF control where we grabbed the Win32 handle from the Java application. Eventing can be tricky, but it can be done.